# What is elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, cypher

I'm just wanting to know what is exactly Elastic Search.
It is said it helps to search data but when I see some webinars it feels like I have to replicate my data in a kind of Elastic datastore... which not means very otpimized to me. In that way all modification done on left hand will have to be reported on right hand and data returned by Elastic Search may not be in the right format.
Can Elastic Search can directly search in my database?

It's to use with a Neo4J graph database. Does somebody already did something like that? Does that only replace the Cypher queries?

Thanks for advices, helping me on realize on what Elastic Search can really helps on our project.

Comment: Imagine ElasticSearch like it _is_ a database.

Comment: Elasticsearch is great for full text search. They are a bridge created by graphaware between Neo4j and Elasticsearch in order to search and add relevancy depending to a Neo4j query. See https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch

I only see an introduction about this product.

Comment: You should not see Elasticsearch as a database but as an index which help you to fast access to the node you search in Neo4j.

Comment: @Quentin , Elastic Search do not send me back any node that I can use, but some data in other format that I use then to search more efficiently in Neo4J? is that right?

Comment: @user954156 You are right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Elasticsearch *is* a database, however it's not a relational database like you may be used to. It is a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.

You insert JSON documents into an index. You query that index to find documents that match a particular criterion.

It is also sharded and node distributed, which gives it resilience and scalability, and also - if you set it up right - performance.

This means it's really good at 'search engine' style database queries, but because it's not relational, it cannot do the equivalent of a SQL JOIN operation very easily.

One example use case is logstash and kibana - known as the ELK stack - where system event logs (syslog, httpd logs, that kind of thing) are processed by logstash to parse metadata - like log source, referrer, URL, session ID, etc. - and then inserted into elasticsearch.

As each event is a self contained piece of information, this is what elasticsearch does particularly well.

You can then use Kibana as a visualisation engine to display your logs, but also perform analysis - most hit pages, geographic distribution of requests, incoming referrers, time based distribution of requests, etc.

But it also collates these logs, so if you run a really large, geographically distributed website with multiple webserver nodes - or maybe you just have a lot of servers in your computer room and want to summarise the system logs - you can feed the whole lot into elastic search.

It's design is such that it's good at handling near-real-time data insertion and analysis. It also works quite well for 'forum style' data models, as essentially all you're doing is querying a list of posts with a particular forum name, and finding replies to a particular parent node - but they're standalone 'documents'.

So yes, you probably could use it to search an existing database, but you'll have to think about your data model - you can't just translate a conventional relational model, you would have to flatten it. Denormalisation is something of a sin in RDBMS terms, but it's actually quite good for search engines, because you can execute queries in parallel more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

There exist some way to combine both approaches. Have a look at this blog post:

http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/09/30/recommendations-with-neo4j-and-graph-aided-search.html

Answer (score 1):

Databases cannot be optimized for all use cases, but luckily there are many databases available so we can choose the best one for each task.

Elasticsearch is optimized for:

- Filtering of documents (exact match)
- Search ranking of documents (relevance of search terms)
- Aggregation of results (sums, distinct counts, percentiles, ...)

Neo4j is optimized for:

- Graph traversal (naturally)
- High performance when operated on a "local" graph neighborhood (context)

Actually both databases use the same underlying library [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) to "index" data to be searched later.

Answer (score 0):

ES is an open source, distributed, RESTful, JSON-based search engine. It is easy to use, scalable and flexible. The indexing feature helps in fast retrieval of search queries.